# How to Includepicture using word using a link?

Tags: ms-word

I am developing a CRM for my company, the CRM give me the ability to generate documents using variables inside a WORD template.

I need to generate a QR code inside the quotes and invoices in order to find it easily inside the CRM. So I found this tool : https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=www.example.com/

Here is the variable given by the CRM for the document: {=Document:ID}
When I put it inside the document it gives me per example the ID of the deal.

All theses kind of variables works inside the documents but when I try to put it on an Includepicture like that :

INCLUDEPICTURE "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=www.example.com/{=Document:ID}"

It doesnt work and somehow it automatically delete the variable and keep only :

INCLUDEPICTURE "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=www.example.com/"

The is any way to be able to put a variable inside a link using Includepicture ?

I hope the question is clear and I thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

An INCLUDEPICTURE field *can* contain another field, but the field braces (i.e. {}) can't be typed - you need to insert the actual sharepoint field where 'www.example.com' is shown in your example.